odoo: error: no such option: --upgrade-path
I am trying to upgrade the odoo 16 to 17 from docker and when I run the following command
PYTHONPATH=/home/swastika/Desktop/openupgrade_17/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages odoo -c /etc/odoo16_17.conf --database=odoo_local --upgrade-path=/home/swastika/Desktop/openupgrade_17 --load=base,web,openupgrade_framework --update all --stop-after-init
I get the following error:
Usage: odoo [options]
odoo: error: no such option: --upgrade-path
I want to upgrade my odoo version 16 to 17 from inside the Docker container
